# How to write a Shell Script using the condition from a database

Tags: shell-script, postgresql

Consider this is the condition I need to check

```
select count(*) from nm.table1 where column1 =true;
```

Now it should come out of the db (PostgreSQL) and use `IF THEN ELSE LOOP` in the Unix

Something like

```
if [ $count > 1]
then
  echo " Successful"
else
  exit
fi
```

Comment: `if [ "$(psql -tAc 'select count(*) from nm.table1 where column1 =true'")" > 1 ]; then echo "Successful"; else exit; fi`? Of course, the connection will probably require a few more options.

Comment: @manatwork, ITYM `-gt` instead of `>`

Comment: Oops. Of course. Thank you, @StephaneChazelas. (I am used with `[[`.)

Comment: @manatwork: Thanks for your response..but i'm getting the error as 
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "select count(*) from nm.table1 where column1 =true"

Comment: @manatwork, even in `[[...]]` `>` is for string comparison. For numeric comparison it's `(( x > y ))` or `[[ $x -gt $y ]]` or `[ "$x" -gt "$y" ]`.

Answer (score 3):

The following assumes that the unix user running psql has a postgresql account which is capable of accessing 'nm.table1'.  If not, you will also need to provide authentication details to psql.

The best way to do that is to have a [~/.pgpass](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpass) file containing the authentication details.

Anyway, once authentication is sorted out, getting data from `psql` queries is as easy as getting data from any other command, standard [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) does the job.

For `psql`, we want to use the `-t` or `--tuples-only` option to disable printing headers and footers, and the `-A` or `--no-align` option for unaligned printing mode (i.e. don't print extra spaces to pad the output).  And, of course, the `-c` or `--command` option to tell `psql` that the next argument will be an SQL command to execute.

```
count=$(psql -tAc 'select count(*) from nm.table1 where column1=true;')

if [ "$count" -gt "1" ] ; then
  echo " Successful"
else
  exit
fi
```

Comment: :How to include the database name..consider the database name as shiva
I tried something like psql -d $1 -U postgres...
Passing the argument as shiva...but it is not working...
the error which i'm getting is
extra command-line argument

Comment: assuming that `$1` actually contains a valid pg dbname, that should work (but it's good practice to quote all variables including positional parameters - i.e. use `"$1"` rather than just `$1`).  Also, if you're using a `~/.pgaccess` file as I suggested, you won't need `-U postgres`.